# Centering a relative sized image

Tags: css, centering

I have a square image that I want to have centered on the screen. Problem is that I want the image to stay a square, while being not more than 80% of both the width and the height. I have used the following code, which makes my image 80% of the height (when height < width), and centers the image vertically, but not horizontally of course. When using a fixed width, I could have used margin-left: 50%; margin-right: 50%, but with relative size, this would set the left side of the image at 50%. Any ideas?

```css
.my_img{
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.my_img_container {
    position: relative;
}
.my_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/l0wskilled/voubtxrt/

Comment: Update to what I0w_skilled said .. 
Change transform: translate(-50%,-50%); to transform: translate(-50%,100%); ....
other wise the top of the image won't display.

Comment: If you put `translate(-50%,100%)` you add the height of the element to the `top: 50%`
Thats wrong. Try it urself in the fiddle i posted, you will offset it.

Comment: Thanks l0w_skilled, your solution worked (with translate(-50%, -50%). I had to include "width:100%; height:100%" to my_img_container.

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help. You should search before you post next time. These are such basic questions, they have been answered alot.

Answer (score 1):

if your image has `display: block` then you can probably use `margin: auto auto` and remove the % margins. If its `display` is `inline` or `inline-block`, you can use `text-align: center` on the parent element of the image to make it horizontally centered. I have not tested this code. If this doesn't work, and you have no problem with jQuery, this can be done with few lines of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" class="my_img" />
</div>
```

With the style:

```
.my_img {
   max-width: 80%;
   max-height: 80%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

I think this is what you are wanting anyway, maybe i'm wrong!
https://jsfiddle.net/dLozvcmo/2/